# how to add message map to dynamic menu item in MFC

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, visual-c++, contextmenu, popupmenu

I writing a MFC which has a listview control. When the user right clicks any item , I am generating a dynamic menu item with that text that is selected in listview. Everything is displaying properly, but I do not know how to add a message map to that dynamic menu item.

Any help?

```
void CMyListDlg::OnRclickList(NMHDR* pNMHDR, LRESULT* pResult) 
    {
        // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here


        int nIndex = m_List.GetSelectionMark();
        CString pString = m_List.GetItemText(nIndex,1);
        CMenu menu, * pSubMenu;
        int pos=0;
        menu.LoadMenu(IDR_MENU1);
        pSubMenu = menu.GetSubMenu (0);
        pSubMenu->DeleteMenu(0,MF_BYPOSITION);
        pSubMenu->InsertMenu(pos,MF_BYPOSITION,NULL,pString);
            CPoint oPoint;
        GetCursorPos (& oPoint);
        pSubMenu-> TrackPopupMenu (TPM_LEFTALIGN, oPoint.x, oPoint.y, this);






        *pResult = 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

At the moment you are inserting the menu item with ID = 0 (NULL). That way you can't figure out which command was pressed. You have to assign an ID to the item, the simplest one is to

```
#define WM_MYMESSAGE WM_USER + 1
```

then you insert it like this:

```
pSubMenu->InsertMenu(pos,MF_BYPOSITION,WM_MYMESSAGE,pString);
```

If you override `OnCommand` for your window, you get your ID as `wParam`.
To actually figure out what happened, store some additional information in another class member, like `m_nLastItemClicked` or ... you get the idea?!

Comment: I dont exactly understand how to override onCommand, my message map has this currently ON_COMMAND(IDM_FILE_OPEN, OnFileOpen)

Comment: You simply add the ON_COMMAND(WM_MYMESSAGE, OnMyMessage) handler, assuming you used WM_MYMESSAGE on InsertMenu

Answer (score 2):

Check the [MFCIE sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177540(VS.80).aspx), it generates a favorite menu from the user's favorite folder and navigates to the favorite url when a favorite menu item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `ON_COMMAND` (and `ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI` if necessary) handlers for the menu items' IDs on your class.

Comment: but these are dynamic menu items, for which I do not know the ID's

Comment: do you know the range of possible ID numbers? In that case you could add ON_COMMAND_RANGE

Comment: I am generating just one menu item. I tried using the ON_COMMAND_RANGE, but could understand how to use this for unknown ( just 1) dynamic menu

Comment: @dwo provided the correct answer, I didn't realize you were inserting the menu item with NULL as the ID.